# How to properly use the same AngularJS 1.5 component multiple times in a view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a set of widgets with AngularJS 1.5's new components. The problem is, when using the same widget multiple times, they somehow share their controller or scope. I thought one of the things about components was that their scope is completely isolated?

---

My main html template which hold the widgets:

```
<widget-list
    title="Books"
    class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>

<widget-list
    title="Movies"
    class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>

<widget-list
    title="Albums"
    class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>
```

My widget template:

```
<div class="widget widget-list">
    <div class="panel b-a">

        <div class="panel-heading b-b b-light">
            <h5>{{$widget.title}}</h5>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="$widget.doSomething()">
                    Do something
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-content">
            {{$widget.content || 'No content'}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My widget component:

```
app.component('widgetList', {
    templateUrl: 'template/widget/widget-list.html',
    bindings: {
        title   : '@',
    },
    controllerAs: '$widget',
    controller: function($timeout) {

        $widget = this;

        console.log('Title on init: ', $widget.title)

        $timeout(function() {
            console.log('Title after 3 seconds: ', $widget.title)
        }, 3000)

        $widget.doSomething = function() {
            $widget.content = "Something";
        }
    }
});
```

---

When running my code, this is what my console looks like:

```
Title on init: Books
Title on init: Movies
Title on init: Albums
(3) Title after 3 seconds: Albums
```

---

Also after rendering, all three widgets display `No content` in their template. But, when clicking the `doSomething()` button in either one of the three widgets, only the content of the last widget updates to `Something`.

What is happening here? Why are my components not 'isolated'?

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: only in my imagination :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a global variable called $widget here, try this:

```
var $widget = this;
```

instead of

```
$widget = this;
```

It creates a mess since the $widget variable holds a reference to the controller that has been recently initialized, in this case to the controller of the third component.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you are declaring the `$widget` on window scope, that's why your controller prints the last value, bacause it was being overridden every time the controller was getting instantiated. Use a `var $widget` instead and your code will work fine.

The following snippet solves this issue:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .component('widgetList', {
    templateUrl: 'template/widget/widget-list.html',
    bindings: {
      title: '@',
    },
    controllerAs: '$widget',
    controller: WidgetListController
  });

function WidgetListController($timeout) {

  var $widget = this;

  console.log('Title on init: ', $widget.title)

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log('Title after 3 seconds: ', $widget.title)
  }, 3000)

  $widget.doSomething = function() {
    $widget.content = "Something";
  }
}

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<widget-list title="Books" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>

<widget-list title="Movies" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>

<widget-list title="Albums" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</widget-list>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/widget/widget-list.html">
  <div class="widget widget-list">
    <div class="panel b-a">

      <div class="panel-heading b-b b-light">
        <h5>{{$widget.title}}</h5>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="$widget.doSomething()">
            Do something
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-content">
        {{$widget.content || 'No content'}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```